# Flutter - Set list tiles height

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a dynamic horizontal list view. When I create the listview however, it takes up the remaining vertical space on the page. I have tried using containers to restrict the height but haven't had any success. Here is what I have tried so far:

List tile...

```
  class CardTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final GreetingCard greetingCard;

  const CardTile({Key key, this.greetingCard}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Container(
        height: 150.0,
        width: 80.0,
        child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Center(child: Text(greetingCard.ocassion)),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

List view builder:

```
  class CardList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardListState createState() => _CardListState();
}

class _CardListState extends State<CardList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final greetingsCards = Provider.of<List<GreetingCard>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: greetingsCards.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return Card(
            child: CardTile(greetingCard: greetingsCards[index],));
      }, scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal);
  }
}
```

[image]

How can I limit the height to say, 150 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the height of the ListView.builder:

```
Container(
  height: 150.0,
  child: ListView.builder(
    ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: I must have tried every level...apart from that one! Many thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm happy to help!